# how can i prove the master theorem for quicksort

Tags: algorithm, math, quicksort

i have a question regarding the algorithm, quicksort.
Can someone explain me how i get to the result (proof) 2T(n/2) + Θ(n) ? 
And what that result means : T(n-1) + Θ(n).

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Please don't just post homework questions. If you are stuck on something, say what it is and show what you have done.

Comment: it is not a homework question it is in the book just an understandig question

Comment: You still need to show us that you have done significant work on the problem. You also should tell us what you do understand, so we don't belabor what you already know. In this case, do you understand the partition algorithm? Do you understand how Quicksort basically partitions the list into two sublists then sorts each sublist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Master theorem states that,

For any [image: main function],

1. If [image: 1st condition] for some constant [image: Epsilon > 0], then [image: T(n)].
2. If [image: 2nd condition], then [image: formula].
3. If [image: 3rd condition], for some constant [image: epsilon], and if [image: function] for some constant [image: c < 1] and all sufficiently large [image: n], then [image: T(n)]

As for yours,
[image: function],
[image: a = 2, b = 2]
Here,
[image: Theta] (2nd condition)
So the complexity will be: [image: complexity]

For your second question, to understand this function [image: 2nd question], you need to understand divide and conquer method. In quick sort, for **n** items if you take the last value as pivot, the number of items will decrease by **1**, which will reduce the number of items to **(n-1)**, Now if you recursively call quick sort taking last value as pivot, each time one item will be reduced. Thus the complexity will be [image: 2nd question], which is not the case when you take middle value as pivot.

Answer (score 0):

here get this i will solve T(n-1)+O(N) by O i mean theta 
so let m=2^n so that log(m)=n

now lets declare a new function S(m)=T(log m)

now lets say

S(m)=S(m/2)+log(m)

now do you agree S(m/2)+log(m) is equal to T(n-1)+n?

because if m=2^n so m/2=2^(n-1) so that log m(n-1) and we already established that logm=(n)

so now that we have established S(m/2)+log(m)=T(n-1)+n lets solve 
S(m/2)+log(m) with the master theorem that will be with the help of the extended case 2 which states [press the link to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHu41.png) so if we follow it we get that log2(1)=0
and that f(m)=logm=O(logm)=O((n^0)*logm) when k is 1 and thus we get that S(m)=O(log^2 m)
or O(n^2) which is known to bee the worst case for quick sort